# Homepage redirect in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

When user comes to my site, http://xyz.com/, one of two things can happen:

1. User not logged in

   - I want users to redirect to `users/login`
2. User logged in(active session)

   - I want users to redirect to `dashboard/`

I've modified the routes:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
```

The login redirection is working fine and redirecting to dashboard, but when i click on homepage it is taking me to `users/`

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Could you please show us the code you are using for redirecting?
Are you using the Authentication Component? I would recomend to use it, because it has a lot of built in functionality you could use.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
```